# Is there is any Stack Exchange community for stock market?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'd like to learn about Indian stock market.

Is there is any Stack Exchange community for questions relating to the stock market?

Comment: there is no specific site for Indian Stock market.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[money](https://money.stackexchange.com) might be the community you are looking for.

Take a look at the Q&A under [stock-markets](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stock-markets#) tag